# How to Print the 1st Character after taking a string input using s.nextLine() in JAVA?

Tags: java

Can anyone suggest me what to do in this code to print the first character of the string?

```
import java.util.*;

class SortingMachine
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int N=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
            {
            String s;
            s=sc.nextLine();
            s=s.replaceAll("\\s","");
            s=s.toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your code already does this. What functionality is this code not exhibiting that you are expecting it to?

Comment: Add `sc.nextLine()` after `sc.nextInt()`...

Comment: `System.out.println(s.charAt(0));` Printing the first character of `s` is what this statement's doing

Answer (score 1):

use `sc.next()` instead `sc.nextLine()`. 
Also close the `Scanner` after using it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        String s;
        s = sc.next();   // -----------------------> change here!!!!
        s = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
    }
    sc.close();   // close the Scanner!!!
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2
AAAAAA
a
BBBBBB
b
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Previously i tried to use sc.next() but didn't close the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were getting a StringOutOfBoundsException, because sc.nextLine() will not wait for any input, it will just advance the scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. The trouble is, there was no more input, so it gets an empty string. The you try and print the 1st character in the empty string, and boom!

To fix, the scanner will actually need to wait for the user to enter something. See Jordi Castilla's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting Integers,

```
public class Tests {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    String s = String.valueOf(N);
    char[] arr  = s.toCharArray();
    System.out.print("First Characater: "+arr[0]);
    sc.close();   // close the Scanner!!!
  }
}
```

In this case you have to think about two edge cases,

1) Which type of input you are expecting. If its integer then use `int N = sc.nextInt();`

2)If you are expecting Integer then it must be less than Integer MAX value.

But if you use `String input = sc.nextLine();` then you can get any kind of input as a String. After that you have to convert it to what ever data type which you need. And make sure input is not a empty string.